# Activation function on output layer results in no progress in training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, chess

I am currently working on a chess engine, more specifically on evaluating certain positions and returning the probabilty for a win(1)/draw(0.5)/loss(0). I am using Tensorflow and self created data, which is equaly distributed, around 200,000 different chessboard states. A chess board has the size 70(64 files + 6 extra info). The problem is, when i choose a activation function for the last layer to clip the values between 0 and 1. The error stays the same after the first epoch. I am new to Tensorflow, but i know how NNs work and have basic a understanding of the topic.

```py
#Loading data
inp, out = loadData("pathname", 200000)

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(inp, out, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
```

I choose the sigmoid-function, but I also tried a custom function `tf.clip_by_value(x,clip_value_min=0,clip_value_max=1)`.
I also played around with the losses, but the loss was still constant.

```py
#Architecture
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(70,), dtype=tf.int8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(700, 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, 'relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid'),
])
```

```py
model.compile('adam', 'mae', ['mae'])
```

Adjusting the batch_size made no diffrence either.

```py
model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, validation_data=[X_val, Y_val], epochs=20, batch_size=64,callbacks=tensorboard_callback)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 19s 4ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
Epoch 2/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 20s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
Epoch 3/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 19s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
Epoch 4/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 20s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
Epoch 5/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 20s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
Epoch 6/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 19s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4856 - mae: 0.4856 - val_loss: 0.4865 - val_mae: 0.4865
...
```

So i tried the same, without a activation function in the last layer and voila

```
Epoch 1/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 18s 4ms/step - loss: 0.3748 - mae: 0.3748 - val_loss: 0.2684 - val_mae: 0.2684
Epoch 2/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 18s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2629 - mae: 0.2629 - val_loss: 0.2514 - val_mae: 0.2514
Epoch 3/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 18s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2450 - mae: 0.2450 - val_loss: 0.2404 - val_mae: 0.2404
Epoch 4/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 19s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2294 - mae: 0.2294 - val_loss: 0.2320 - val_mae: 0.2320
Epoch 5/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 17s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2166 - mae: 0.2166 - val_loss: 0.2228 - val_mae: 0.2228
Epoch 6/20
4079/4079 [==============================] - 18s 4ms/step - loss: 0.2065 - mae: 0.2065 - val_loss: 0.2170 - val_mae: 0.2170
...
```

I know these values are far from good, but i want to get this working first before gathering more data to train and fine-tuning the model.

How could I fix the model, so i get better results ?

Comment: You cannot use softmax with a single neuron, think about what possible value it outputs.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Ah yes you are right, but the problem persists when using sigmodi, or manual clipping.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy  I am  currently using sigmod as output activation and the loss over 10 epochs are 0.5135 constant

Comment: Are the label values normalized to the same range?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy For example 0 is completley losing but 0.25 is only losing and 0.4 is a disadvatage for instance. They are no clear labels.

Comment: You should normalize the labels so they are exactly in the [0, 1] range.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Maybe i am missunderstanding what you suggest. But each desired output is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Your previous message suggests values between 0 and 0.4

Comment: I see this was confusing. 0  -> 1 is lossing to winning for White

Comment: the logs in the question are referred to the training with softmax or with sigmoid?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia sigmoid, but i tried binary_crossentropy with sigmoid and it seems to work now